# JSON Path to return whole json which matches predicate

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have usecase where I would need JSON Path to return whole json structure which matches its predicate.

```
   {
  "store" : {
    "book" : [
      {
        "category" : "reference",
        "author" : "Nigel Rees",
        "title" : "Sayings of the Century",
        "price" : 8.95,
       },
     {
        "category" : "fiction",
        "author" : "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title" : "Sword of Honour",
        "price" : 12.99
     },
     {
        "category" : "fiction",
        "author" : "Herman Melville",
        "title" : "Moby Dick",
        "isbn" : "0-553-21311-3",
        "price" : 8.99
     },
     {
        "category" : "fiction",
        "author" : "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title" : "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn" : "0-395-19395-8",
        "price" : 22.99
     }
  ],
  "bicycle" : {
     "color" : "red",
     "price" : 19.95
  }
  },
    "expensive" : 10
}
```

This is my `json path expression`

```
$.store.book[?(@.category in ['reference'])]
```

which returns

```
 [
{
  "category" : "reference",
  "author" : "Nigel Rees",
  "title" : "Sayings of the Century",
  "price" : 8.95
 }
```

]

But I want the whole path, like below,

```
{ 
  "store" : {
     "book" : [
        {
  "category" : "reference",
  "author" : "Nigel Rees",
  "title" : "Sayings of the Century",
  "price" : 8.95
 }

        ] 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a thing that JSON Path can do usually, but check with your specific implementation.

Typically JSON Path can return the matches or the paths to them.  Getting a match nested as it appears in the original structure isn't supported.

You might be able to extrapolate what you need from the path, however.  The path to that item would be `$.store.book[0]`.  To rebuild the object you want, you need...

```
$        // start, no impact
.store  // create an object with "store"
.book   // create an object with "book"
[0]     // since this is the last thing, replace this with the match
```

Looking at this, it seems there would be a problem trying to support this if the match is further into an array rather than right at the start.  For example, if you had matched `[2]` instead of `[0]`, you'd still get the same nested structure you posted.  (Not here to discuss how this could work; just explaining why it doesn't now.)